# Rails app is not working with subdomain on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application developed on Rails4 and Ruby2 and i have an issue with this application on production.
Actually i am redirecting every user to his subdomain and from there user can manage his account, but the problem is that App is working fine on the main domain like: www.domain.com
but when user being redirected to his subdomain like: subdomain.domain.com then getting Server not found.
and locally it is working fine with the help of lvh.me all subdimains and everything.

I am using Apache2+Passenger On server.

Is there anything which i have to change in my Apache config ?

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com *.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/deploy/myapp/public
 <Directory /home/deploy/myapp/public>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Middleware**

I've found the best way to handle subdomains with Apache is to rely on the Rails middleware. It's not as efficient as I would like, but equally effective.

You can do this:

```
#etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/deploy/myapp/public
 <Directory /home/deploy/myapp/public>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you use a [wildcard DNS setting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) for your subdomain, you'll be able to route all your incoming "subdomain" requests to your domain, allowing Rails to determine the routing based on the subdomain

Comment: Thanks @Rich Peck, trying this wildcard DNS.

Comment: Can't find anything helpful, @Rich Peck could you please guide me how to setup this  wildcard DNS? plz

Comment: I have added *.domain in my A record.